# Why isn't my internal API structure executing successfully in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I am a noob and I am puzzled about my problem. My understanding might be limited, I looked up some similiar questions and I find different problems, like my missing init (I have no clue how init works).

So! I try to use an external API via JSON. You'll find it here (https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians). My Code was working fine, till i wanted to add an internal structure "party" (in my code "partei"), next to my working "Politician" structure. After research, I thought I need to build the code structure like in my code. I used different names for id and label, to make it work via codingkeys.

I experience these bugs currently

> "58:28 Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
> ->In call to function 'decode(_:from:)' (Foundation.JSONDecoder)
>
> 58:43 Cannot convert value of type 'module' to expected argument type 'T.Type'
>
> 108:88 Missing argument for parameter 'partei' in call
> ->'init(politician:partei:)' declared here

My plan was to add another Text from the internal structure Partei to my PoliticanDetailView

> 

```
        List(viewModel.parteien, id: \.parteiID) { partei in
            Text("Partei: \(partei.namePartei)")
```

My whole messy code, I am sorry if it might be not etiquette conform

```
import SwiftUI

struct Partei: Decodable {
    let parteiID: Int
    let namePartei: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case parteiID = "id"
        case namePartei = "label"
    }
}

struct Politician: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let birthYear: Int?
    let beruf: String?
    let geschlecht: String?
    let partei: Partei
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case birthYear = "year_of_birth"
        case beruf = "occupation"
        case geschlecht = "sex"
        case partei
    }
    
}


struct Politicians: Decodable {
    let data: [Politician]
}

actor PoliticianDataService {
    func fetchPoliticians() async throws -> [Politician] {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians") else { return [] }
        
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let politicians = try decoder.decode(Politicians.self, from: data)
        return politicians.data
    }
}

actor ParteiDataService {
    func fetchParteien() async throws -> [Partei] {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/parties") else { return [] }

        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let parteien = try decoder.decode(Parteien.self, from: data)
        return parteien.data
    }
}

@MainActor
class PoliticianListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var politicians = [Politician]()
    
    private var dataService = PoliticianDataService()
    
    init() {
        // Additional setup could be done here if needed
    }
    
    func fetchPoliticians() {
        Task {
            do {
                let fetchedPoliticians = try await dataService.fetchPoliticians()
                politicians = fetchedPoliticians
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

class PoliticianDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var parteien = [Partei]()

    private var dataService = ParteiDataService()

    func fetchParteien() {
        Task {
            do {
                let fetchedParteien = try await dataService.fetchParteien()
                parteien = fetchedParteien
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = PoliticianListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.politicians, id: \.id) { politician in
                NavigationLink(destination: PoliticianDetailView(politician: politician)) {
                    Text("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Politiker in Deutschland")
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchPoliticians()
        }
    }
}

struct PoliticianDetailView: View {
    let politician: Politician
    let partei: Partei
    

    @StateObject private var viewModel = PoliticianDetailViewModel()  // Create a ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Name: \(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
            Text("Geburtsjahr \(politician.birthYear ?? 0)")
            Text("Alter: \(calculateAge(birthYear: politician.birthYear ?? 0)) Jahre")
            Text("Beschäftigt als \(politician.beruf ?? "Unbekannt")")
            Text("Geschlecht: \(politician.geschlecht ?? "Unbekannt")")

            List(viewModel.parteien, id: \.parteiID) { partei in
                Text("Partei: \(partei.namePartei)")
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.fetchParteien()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
    }

    func calculateAge(birthYear: Int) -> Int {
        let currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
        return currentYear - birthYear
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: List(viewModel.parteien, id: \.parteiID) { partei in
                Text("Partei: \(partei.namePartei)")-> IDK about this one, i found this somewhere, i dont want to create a list, instead a simple text, but i experience a lot of errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code.

The first error occurs because you want to decode `Parteien.self` but you don't have a `Parteien` structure.

```
struct Parteien: Decodable {
    let data: [Partei]
}
```

But, you don't really need that structure or to fetch the parties, because the party is in the `Politician` structure already.

The second error occurs because you have declared a property `partei` in your `PoliticianDetailView` struct, but you aren't passing in a value.  Again, you don't need that property because it is already in the `Politician`.

Instead of using a `List` you can just use an additional `Text`.

```
struct PoliticianDetailView: View {
    let politician: Politician

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Name: \(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
            Text("Geburtsjahr \(politician.birthYear ?? 0)")
            Text("Alter: \(calculateAge(birthYear: politician.birthYear ?? 0)) Jahre")
            Text("Beschäftigt als \(politician.beruf ?? "Unbekannt")")
            Text("Geschlecht: \(politician.geschlecht ?? "Unbekannt")")

            Text("Party: \(politician.partei.namePartei)")
        }
        .navigationTitle("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
    }

    func calculateAge(birthYear: Int) -> Int {
        let currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
        return currentYear - birthYear
    }
}
```

Finally, you will get a runtime error because your `CodingKeys` for `Partei` doesn't map the `party` property from your JSON to `partei` in your structure:

```
struct Politician: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let birthYear: Int?
    let beruf: String?
    let geschlecht: String?
    let partei: Partei
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case birthYear = "year_of_birth"
        case beruf = "occupation"
        case geschlecht = "sex"
        case partei = "party"
    }
}
```

Also, you could tweak your age calculation so that it doesn't show people without a birth year as being 2023 years old

```
struct PoliticianDetailView: View {
    let politician: Politician
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Name: \(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
            Text("Geburtsjahr \(politician.birthYear ?? 0)")
            Text("Alter: \(calculateAge(birthYear: politician.birthYear))")
            Text("Beschäftigt als \(politician.beruf ?? "Unbekannt")")
            Text("Geschlecht: \(politician.geschlecht ?? "Unbekannt")")
            
            Text("Party: \(politician.partei.namePartei)")
        }
        .navigationTitle("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
    }
    
    func calculateAge(birthYear: Int?) -> String {
        guard let birthYear else {
            return "---"
        }
        let currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
        return String(currentYear - birthYear)+" jahre"
    }
}
```

And add a sorting by last name:

```
actor PoliticianDataService {
    func fetchPoliticians() async throws -> [Politician] {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians") else { return [] }
        
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let politicians = try decoder.decode(Politicians.self, from: data)
        return politicians.data.sorted {
            $0.lastName < $1.lastName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, Thank you for the effort, I will check this thoroughly tonight. Unfortunately i still experience an error "13:88 Missing argument for parameter 'partei' in call". In this line "var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.politicians, id: \.id) { politician in
                NavigationLink(destination: PoliticianDetailView(politician: politician))". I only want to list Politician.

Comment: You must not have deleted the line `let partei: Partei` from `PoliticianView`

Comment: Thank you! I took my time and reread everything and I understood the logic. I reworked my code and it worked. If you don't mind, I have another question. What if I want to decode an api which contains references to another external api. Like on this page on the bottom, they'll added references like Fraction and Poll.

Comment: https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/entitaeten/vote

Comment: You can either fetch that data at the same time and the refer to it when you display or, in the case of a poll, you might fetch the data when the detail of that poll is displayed.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to google and further testing :D

Comment: hey i worked on my code, could you glance over it and tell me if its okay? its also fine to post it in comments or somehow else?